# libusb crash when run as non root user

Tags: libusb, libusb-1.0

backtrace :

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7bca558 in add_to_flying_list (transfer=0x6527b0) at io.c:1364
1364            struct libusb_context *ctx = ITRANSFER_CTX(transfer);
(gdb) bt

## 0  0x00007ffff7bca558 in add_to_flying_list (transfer=0x6527b0) at io.c:1364

## 1  libusb_submit_transfer (transfer=transfer@entry=0x652848) at io.c:1483

## 2  0x00007ffff7bcc779 in do_sync_bulk_transfer (dev_handle=0x0, endpoint=, buffer=0x613728  "\f", length=8, transferred=0x7fffffffe7c0, timeout=1000,

```
type=type@entry=2 '\002') at sync.c:174
```

## 3  0x00007ffff7bccb14 in libusb_bulk_transfer (dev_handle=, endpoint=, data=, length=, transferred=,

```
timeout=<optimized out>) at sync.c:257
```

## 4  0x0000000000402cfa in dm_usb_send (context=0x652010, msg_ptr=0x613728 ) at rel/1.0/src/dm-usb-context.c:136

does any one see this kind of crash only when you run as non root user ? (works fine when run as root)

Comment: strace gives me permission denied error open("/dev/bus/usb/003/028", O_RDWR)    = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)  for non sudo

Answer (score 0):

I got this crash because of Permission issues.I have added myself to plugdev group.After adding to plugdev group didnt see the crash